# Can't upgrade to trusty

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, 14.04

I try this to upgrade but just get an error:

```
nick@netbook:~$ sudo update-manager
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
WARNING:root:file 'trusty.tar.gz.gpg' missing
nick@netbook:~$
```

The GUI just says:

```
Failed to fetch Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

There is not a network problem, all other network stuff works and this has been happening for weeks.

Any idea of what actions I should take to sort this?

Cheers
Nick

Comment: Have you tried?: sudo update-manager -d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following things:

1. Update your sources.list file. You can get a fresh copy from [this website](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) if you are in doubt.
2. If you are behind a proxy server, add -E with sudo to preserve the environment variables.
3. Use a different mirror

Now your commands will be

```
sudo -E apt-get update
sudo -E apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: This put my in the right direction.  I regenerated source.list and it still failed, but then I changed nz.archive.ubuntu.com -> archive.ubuntu.com and it worked fine.

Obviously something wrong with the NZ mirrors, I also found that this was a problem back in 2012: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1990842

Comment: Cool, I've added that in my answer.
PS: Don't forget to upvote all the helpful answers as this helps others with similar issues

Answer (score 0):

From command line:

*sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade*

#### first part updates apt-cache, second part installs major upgrades

OR

*sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install*
*sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade*

Comment: I ran that and it produced a lot of output and ended with:

Fetched 974 kB in 26s (36.7 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

I tried running the software updater again and for the same failed to fetch.